# AS3: Can I dispatch Event from one Child to another?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, dispatcher, children

[image]

Hi guys, I cannot sort out this enigma :).

How to send dispatchEvent from Child1 and catch this event in Child2?

or

How to send dispatchEvent from Child1 and catch this event in Child3?

or

How to send dispatchEvent from Child3 and catch this event in Child1?

Thanks guys. I will appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I get what you are trying to achieve, I think the better design approach is to allow the container to manage it's children.

For example if container receives an event from child1, it's container's role to take care of notifying the other children if appropriate. This approach also makes it very clear in the container code the basic interaction between all the container's children. If I were going over someone's code, I'd appreciate such methodology for that reason.

That being said, you could have a method in child2 and child3 that would allow you to pass child1 as a parameter, and then add a listener for child1 within. For example :

in container code :

```
child2.setChildListener(child1);
child3.setChildListener(child1);
```

Then in child2 and child3 , you could do something like this :

```
public function setChildListener(childToListenTo:MovieClip):void
{
    childToListenTo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, childClickedHandler);
}

private function childClickedHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // react to the child click here
}
```

Comment: Sorry prototypical I put this as an Answer because I didn't know how to publish this picture as a comment. I am sorry if I break the rules. I will delete this right now.

Comment: No problem, but your answer was a whole new question. You asked for an approach, then you tried to implement and ran into a 'different' issue.

Comment: yes I know it's a mess in my head. I work on this any minute in my off work time, no sleep , no eat. I want to learn this god damn language

Comment: I will be careful next time. Thanks

Comment: haha, no problem. It's best to keep questions to one concise question, as that's what makes it most helpful to others who end up having the same question at some point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to learn how to declare custom events and handle them. 
You have a simple guide here from Adobe : http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AS3__Creating_and_dispatching_Custom_Events-17609.html

You may also want to read about how events bubble and are captured in the following link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a67edfb831266c0b5fc6-8000.html

Now let's go through the cases you ask:

Case 1. From Child 1 to Child 2:
In essence unless Child 2 listens to an event of child 1 it will not be able to capture it since they do not have a parental kind of relationship. 
What you can do is the following: Declare an event in Child 1 and listen and capture it from the container. The container can call a method in Child 2 as a result of the event being triggered from Child 1.

Case 2. From Child 1 to Child 3:
It is basically the same as Child 1 to Child 3, only that when the container calls the Child 2, the Child 2 calls the Child 3 as well.

Case 3. Child 3 to Child 1. Child 3 can raise an event which can bubble up all the way to the Container. The container can then call the desired method in Child 1.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Much appreciated Javier. I need a little time to realize all this. You got my point and I am happy. Thanks again.

Comment: Javier what do you mean in Case 3 by "event which can bubble up all the way to the Container". This doesn't work for me: addEventListener("FromChild3", onFromChild3); I got this in Child 1 and this: dispatchEvent(new Event("FromChild3")); in Child 3

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property thief through a reference with static type Container

Comment: Container.addEventListener("FromChild3", onFromChild3); - nothing happens;
Container.Child2.addEventListener("FromChild3", onFromChild3); - error 1119

Comment: If I trace them: trace (Container) - return [object ContainerMc];
trace (Child2) - return [object Child2Mc];
trace (Container.Child2) - return error 1119;

Comment: For the third case, the container has to listen to the event on child2. If child 2 doesn't handle nor stop the propagation of the event generated in child 3, this will be bubbled up to the Container, whose event handler will be triggered. Once the container has the event triggered by child 3, it can call the method on child 1. Try that see if it works :)