# How can I transfer event from one child to another child if they are from same viewgroup in android?

Tags: android, events, layout

[image]

So far I was able to transfer the event from the parent (viewgroup) to the child. ie When I click child 1, the viewgroup sends the event to child 1 and when I click child 2 (which is under child 1), the viewgroup sends the event to child 2.

**Problem**: What I wanted to do was, When app is in certain state and child 2 is clicked I want the viewgroup to send the event to child 1 instead of child 2.

So far : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264885/as3-can-i-dispatch-event-from-one-child-to-another) link kind of touches the issue but is not in android.

Comment: So you should add event listener to childa 2 then handle its event in viewgroup and call a method in child 1 to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :
In main viewgroup

```
child2.setOnClickListener(new....{

and inside this event handler call an appropriate method in child1 

child1.onSomethingInChild2()
```

Comment: Thank you bryan c for the answer

Answer (score 0):

What i did was inside dispatchTouchEvent of child 2 I test for the state. If the the state is true I called child1.dispatchTouchEvent(event) and passed the event to child 1.

In child 2

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   if(cond == true){
       child1.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
       return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: is the child1's dispatchTouchEvent not get called() or it is but there is not visual effect on the screen

Comment: child1's dispatchTouchEvent does get called but no visual effect on the screen

Comment: try return child1.dispatchTouchEvent(event);