# Why is requestLayout() not calling onLayout() when I transfer event from view to button in Android?

Tags: java, android, layout

I was trying to transfer event from one view to another button. When user touches on the view under a certain condition I wanted to transfer the event to the button. In button inside onTouchEvent I call requestLayout(). This requestLayout() gets called when I click the button but the requestLayout() does not get called when I transfer the event from the view to the button. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535185/how-can-i-transfer-event-from-one-child-to-another-child-if-they-are-from-same-v) is my follow up question to the previous one.

```
/// MaintActivity.java
package com.example.mylayout;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//-------activity_main.xml

```
<com.example.mylayout.MyViewGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.mylayout.MyView 
    android:id="@+id/myview"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green">
    </com.example.mylayout.MyView>

    <com.example.mylayout.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Next"
    android:background="@color/red">
    </com.example.mylayout.MyButton>

</com.example.mylayout.MyViewGroup>
```

//--------MyViewGroup-------
    package com.example.mylayout;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup{



    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

       int count = getChildCount();

       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           final View child = getChildAt(i);

       }

       setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.out.println("I am from MyViewGroup:onLayout");
       for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
           final View child = getChildAt(i);

           if(i == 0)child.layout(0,0,800,800);
           if(i == 1)child.layout(10,10, 200, 200);
       }
   }

}
```

//--------------MyView-------

```
package com.example.mylayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View{

    MyButton objbutton;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);

        objbutton = new MyButton(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        objbutton = new MyButton(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stu
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("I am from MyView: dispatchTouchEvent");
        objbutton.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        return false;
   }
```

}

//-------MyButton----

```
package com.example.mylayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyButton extends Button{

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);

    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stu
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("I am from MyButton: dispatchTouchEvent");
        requestLayout();
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("I am from MyButton: dispatchTouchEvent");
        requestLayout();
        return true;
    }

    void printme(){
        System.out.println("I am from MyButton: printme ..");
    }
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple just to set some click listeners and then call `performClick()` or something?

Comment: Just tried, it works. Have you tried logging or some debugging?

Comment: Hey @razzledazzle thank you for the answer. U mean click listeners in button? or did u meant click listeners in View? I am guessing U meant in the button.

Comment: Yes in button, BTW, your does fine too. Better check the logic inside `adjustContentPosition()` and log it while you're at it to be sure.

Comment: @razzledazzle I have edited the question .. by the way I am able to see the printed value of scrollerOffset

Comment: That's better. Also, you know that `requestLayout()` has repeated there. It would also be nice if you mentioned exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Again, do edit your question title too, as it seems that the method is being called.

Comment: I will do accordingly ... fyi requestLayout() is called but it does not trigger the onLayout() .. when the button is clicked it works ... but when the view is clicked and I transfer the event onLayout is not triggered

Comment: It works here, not sure why yours doesn't. Here is the code. http://pastie.org/private/pylxpjchiepaoevaiy2rw

Comment: @razzledazzle  
Hmm Interesting... But when I do this way www.pastie.org/10797274 I again get the same problem..

Comment: According to your paste, it looks like you're creating an entire new instance of `MyButton` inside `MyView`. It doesn't know of the `MyButton` which you have included in the layout xml. Instead of doing that, create a setter in `MyView` and pass it in from `MainActivity` via `findViewById()`.

Comment: Like this: http://pastie.org/private/bgrrngtkonjsj0ukwla7ua
Btw, this is not a proper way to discuss as everything is here in the comments. Your question might get downvotes for that matter, so I'm warning you. Hope that helps you.

Comment: @razzledazzle So now after following your comment it worked :) .. thank you so much for your patience. Do you think I should answer this question? (I wanted to give you points for your answer )

Comment: Inside MainActivity .. I did ....  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  MyButton mybutton = (MyButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
  
  MyView   myview   = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myview);
  
  //myview
  
  myview.setButton(mybutton);

Comment: It's okay. Write an answer and accept it. Doesn't make sense to answer after the problem has been resolved. Good to see things have worked. Do include the part that was causing problem there and write the correct part as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

According to your paste, it looks like you're creating an entire new instance of `MyButton` inside `MyView`. It doesn't know of the `MyButton` which you have included in the layout xml. Instead of doing that, create a setter in `MyView` and pass it in from `MainActivity` via `findViewById()`.

Like this:

```
package com.example.mylayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

    private MyButton objbutton;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
    }

    public void setMyButton(MyButton myButton) {
        objbutton = myButton;
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("I am from MyView: dispatchTouchEvent");
        if(objbutton != null)
            objbutton.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was just curious why can't MyView not know of the MyButton since I already created its instance by doing new MyButton inside MyView.

Comment: No assumptions are made. Consider this, if layout had more than one button which one do you think that view should refer to?

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't know cause it would have multiple instance of MyButton and would get confused. Is this what you meant?

Comment: What if I could create instance of MyButton inside MyView by specifying the button's id. I guess it would be cumbersome but just a though.

Comment: Yes. And the layout already specifies an instance to be created. This is a nice way to learn, props to you for trying custom stuff in Android. :)

Comment: Regarding your second question, you should keep your `View` independent of other components if they're not interdependent. Here, if you tie `MyButton` and `MyView` with some ID, you're just creating unnecessary constraints and cumbersome it surely will be. Look up on Dependency Injection principles, they will help you.

Comment: But actually, I suggest you create a compound `ViewGroup` with those views and configure them in the `ViewGroup`. That way you can directly refer to that `ViewGroup` in your layout.

Comment: what do u mean by saying configure them(view and button) in the ViewGroup? didn't I do the same ? by placing view and button inside viewgroup

Comment: Similar to how you created `MyView`, you can create a new `ViewGroup` and put all your `findViewById()` and all related code in `ViewGroup`. Search how to create compound `ViewGroup` as this is a large topic.

Comment: Thank you @razzledazzle, I learned a lot from you .. and also respect ur patience :)